# show fxcop result using jenkins pipeline as code

Tags: jenkins, workflow, jenkins-pipeline, static-code-analysis, fxcopcmd

I have pipeline job in jenkins which build the .net solution project. Run the MS Test and also does the static code analysis using FxCopCmd using command line (batch). I would like to show the fxcop result in jenkins itself. I know there is a Violation plug-in already available but it helps in FreeStyle job. How can we show the result using Pipeline Job?